# Laravel 8 Class 'Laravel\Fortify\Actions\Auth' not found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make an e-commerce admin/user authentication I use laravel 8 went register a test account and logged in and this error occured.

Error
Class 'Laravel\Fortify\Actions\Auth' not found

After i logged in a test account it was supposed to result like this
https://ibb.co/Vq5LxBk

C:\Users\ACER\laravel8ecommerce\vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate.php:58

This was the line 58

**if(Auth::user()->utype === 'ADM')**

My code on AttemptToAuthenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Fortify\Actions;


use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter;

class AttemptToAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * The guard implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * The login rate limiter instance.
     *
     * @var \Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter
     */
    protected $limiter;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter  $limiter
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard, LoginRateLimiter $limiter)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;
        $this->limiter = $limiter;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateUsingCallback) {
            return $this->handleUsingCustomCallback($request, $next);
        }

        if ($this->guard->attempt(
            $request->only(Fortify::username(), 'password'),
            $request->filled('remember'))
        ) {
            if(Auth::user()->utype === 'ADM')
            {
                session(['utype'=>'ADM']);
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
            elseif(Auth::user()->utype === 'USR')
            {
                session(['utype'=>'USR']);
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }

        $this->throwFailedAuthenticationException($request);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate using a custom callback.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function handleUsingCustomCallback($request, $next)
    {
        $user = call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateUsingCallback, $request);

        if (! $user) {
            $this->fireFailedEvent($request);

            return $this->throwFailedAuthenticationException($request);
        }

        $this->guard->login($user, $request->filled('remember'));

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Throw a failed authentication validation exception.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function throwFailedAuthenticationException($request)
    {
        $this->limiter->increment($request);

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            Fortify::username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Fire the failed authentication attempt event with the given arguments.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function fireFailedEvent($request)
    {
        event(new Failed(config('fortify.guard'), null, [
            Fortify::username() => $request->{Fortify::username()},
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]));
    }
```

My Routes (web php)

```
<?php

use App\Http\Livewire\CartComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\HomeComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShopComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\User\UserDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);

Route::get('/shop',ShopComponent::class);

Route::get('/cart',CartComponent::class);

Route::get('/checkout',CheckoutComponent::class);
// Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
//    return view('dashboard');
// })->name('dashboard');



// For User or Customer
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('user/dashboard',UserDashboardComponent::class,)->name('user.dashboard');
});

// For Admin
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class,)->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

I would really appreciate a help i'm doing this for my project on school

Comment: Put `use Auth;` at the top of `AttemptToAuthenticate.php`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

from to vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate
```

but you must remove line :

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\RouteServiceProvider;
```

Because this line is duplicate for `RouteServiceProvider....` but maybe just for my project

Answer (score 1):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
```

put these two on top of
vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate

Comment: Thanks for the response Amir, the question appears to have multiple answers that say the same  thing so it may not need an additional answer unless it has something to add of value.

Answer (score 1):

adding two lines on the top of AttemptToAuthenticate.php file

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Munna. The question appears to have multiple answers that say the same thing so it may not need an additional answer unless it has something to add of value.

Answer (score 0):

For future users;

On AttemptToAuthenticate.php, right under `AttemptToAuthenticate.php`,

add `use Auth;`
it will still throw an error class '\laravel\fortify\actions\RouteServiceProvider' not found!

To solve this,

Simply add
`use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;`, to direct it to the default
RouteServiceProvider class.

Answer (score 0):

add
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`
in class `vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Fortify\Actions;


use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

class AttemptToAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * The guard implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * The login rate limiter instance.
     *
     * @var \Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter
     */
    protected $limiter;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\LoginRateLimiter  $limiter
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard, LoginRateLimiter $limiter)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;
        $this->limiter = $limiter;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateUsingCallback) {
            return $this->handleUsingCustomCallback($request, $next);
        }

        if ($this->guard->attempt(
            $request->only(Fortify::username(), 'password'),
            $request->filled('remember'))
        ) {
            if(Auth::user()->utype === 'ADM')
            {
                session(['utype'=>'ADM']);
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
            elseif(Auth::user()->utype === 'USR')
            {
                session(['utype'=>'USR']);
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
            return $next($request);
        }

        $this->throwFailedAuthenticationException($request);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate using a custom callback.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function handleUsingCustomCallback($request, $next)
    {
        $user = call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateUsingCallback, $request);

        if (! $user) {
            $this->fireFailedEvent($request);

            return $this->throwFailedAuthenticationException($request);
        }

        $this->guard->login($user, $request->filled('remember'));

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Throw a failed authentication validation exception.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function throwFailedAuthenticationException($request)
    {
        $this->limiter->increment($request);

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            Fortify::username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Fire the failed authentication attempt event with the given arguments.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function fireFailedEvent($request)
    {
        event(new Failed(config('fortify.guard'), null, [
            Fortify::username() => $request->{Fortify::username()},
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
This line should be added at the top of the AttemptAuthenticate.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i solved by adding these lines. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `AttemptToAuthenticate.php` file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).